Getting blank PDF using Download to Buffer from Blob Storage
I got million errors from this first is Content-Length mismatch: too many bytes written (216523 of 215706)
but when I managed to fix it, I can now successfully download the PDF but it has blank contents
Please help, thank you.
Code:
let blobUrl = fileUrl;

            if (!blobUrl) {
                req.context.log(`Skipping attachment, URL is not yet ready.`, new Date().toString());
                return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Attachment is not ready.' });
            } else {
                let sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(utility.dec(client.storageName), utility.dec(client.storageKey));
                let blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
                    `https://${utility.dec(client.storageName)}.blob.core.windows.net`,
                    sharedKeyCredential
                );

                let urlParts = new URL(blobUrl);
                let pathParts = urlParts.pathname.split('/');
                let blobName = pathParts.slice(2).join('/'); 

                let sourceBlob = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(constants.BLOB_CONTAINER_ATTACHMENT).getBlobClient(blobName);

                req.context.log('Downloading blob:', blobName);

                const pdfFile = await sourceBlob.downloadToBuffer({
                    onProgress: (progress) => {
                      req.context.log(`Downloaded ${progress.loadedBytes} bytes`);
                    }
                  });
                  
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
                res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename="${blobName}"`);
                res.set('Transfer-Encoding', 'identity');
                res.send(pdfFile);`

PDF will have content

Check if below provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?


Getting blank PDF using Download to Buffer from Blob Storage

You can use the below code to download the pdf file with correct content from azure blob storage using JavaScript code.
Code:
const express = require('express');
const { StorageSharedKeyCredential, BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Replace these with your actual values
const client = {
    storageName: 'xxxxx',
    storageKey: 'xxxxxx'
};

const constants = {
    BLOB_CONTAINER_ATTACHMENT: 'test' // Set your blob container name here
};

const utility = {
    dec: (value) => value 
};

app.get('/download', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let fileUrl = req.query.fileUrl; // Get blob URL from query parameter
        if (!fileUrl) {
            return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Attachment is not ready.' });
        }

        let sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(
            utility.dec(client.storageName),
            utility.dec(client.storageKey)
        );
        let blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
            `https://${utility.dec(client.storageName)}.blob.core.windows.net`,
            sharedKeyCredential
        );

        let urlParts = new URL(fileUrl);
        let pathParts = urlParts.pathname.split('/');
        let blobName = pathParts.slice(2).join('/'); 

        let containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(constants.BLOB_CONTAINER_ATTACHMENT);
        let blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);

        const downloadResponse = await blobClient.download(0);
        const chunks = [];
        let downloadedBytes = 0;

        downloadResponse.readableStreamBody.on('data', (chunk) => {
            chunks.push(chunk);
            downloadedBytes += chunk.length;
        });

        downloadResponse.readableStreamBody.on('end', () => {
            const pdfBuffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);

            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
            res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename="${blobName}"`);
            res.setHeader('Content-Length', pdfBuffer.length);
            res.send(pdfBuffer);
        });
        downloadResponse.readableStreamBody.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error('Error while downloading blob:', err.message);
            res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error downloading blob' });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error:', err.message);
        res.status(500).send({ message: 'Internal server error' });
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

The above code extracts the blob name from the URL, and downloads the PDF file as a stream. Finally, it sets the response headers and sends the PDF content to the client.
When I run my example.js file it hits Server running at http://localhost:3000 as output.
Now, When I use with server + blob URL it executed successfully and downloaded the pdf file.
http://localhost:3000/download?fileUrl=https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container name>/<file name>


I also checked the file and it has content.
File:


thanks for answering. but can i use POST instead of GET? my existing code is POST, i just cant show my whole code for privacy purposes of our client.

tried using your code but with POST method and got the same error

Post it has new question and add more details in that question and share here question link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79145738/post-method-getting-blank-pdf-using-download-to-buffer-from-blob-storage?noredirect=1#comment139561100_79145738
got resolved but with a few modifications on my end. thank you!
